# Why asyncio make request with aiohttp still make use of thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I thought `ayncio` and the use of `coroutine` is not related with thread, since `coroutine` is a type of "thread" running under program's scheduler, so there should be only 1 thread running each process. But when I ran examples in [Making 1 million requests with python-aiohttp](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html), the code is like below:

```
# modified fetch function with semaphore
import random
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        delay = response.headers.get("DELAY")
        date = response.headers.get("DATE")
        print("{}:{} with delay {}".format(date, response.url, delay))
        return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)


async def run(r):
    url = "http://localhost:8080/{}"
    tasks = []
    # create instance of Semaphore
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

    # Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
    # per each request.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url.format(i), session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

number = 10000
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

With Windows' Resource Monitor, I found that the code create 25 threads in 1 process.

Answer (score 5):

The aiohttp library uses threads for concurrent DNS resolving by default in order not to block IO loop, see [aiohttp/resolver.py](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/resolver.py). If you want asynchronous DNS lookups, you need to install python package `aiodns`, which in turn uses `pycares`.

You can then do:

```
async def fetch(url):
    resolver = aiohttp.AsyncResolver()
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(resolver=resolver, family=socket.AF_INET)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                print("success!")
```

If you want to set `AsyncResolver` as a global default, this worked for me with aiohttp 2.2.3:

```
import aiohttp.resolver
aiohttp.resolver.DefaultResolver = aiohttp.resolver.AsyncResolver
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's standard library includes a module called [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) which allows to run python code concurrently by using `Thread` instances.  `asyncio` and `aiohttp` does not use the `threading` module to operate.

Python itself might use OS (low level) threads as an implementation detail - but this probably changes between different platforms and versions.  For example, the number of OS threads for a simple `print('hello world'); s = input()` for python 3.6.0 in Windows 10 is 3.

Check out https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/windows_events.py to find clues for what might start OS threads in windows.